# Converting SQL query result to temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to turn my sql results into a temp table but it keeps on returning the following error:

> Expecting As or Id or quoted-ID.

I know the sql result is correct but when I add `SELECT * INTO #newtable FROM`, the sql query doesn't work. **What is wrong?**

```
SELECT *
INTO #newtable
FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        Url,Id 
    FROM Blob 
    WHERE 
        Id IN 
            (
            SELECT 
                BlobId 
            FROM 
                XrefBlobProjectMeeting
            ) 
        AND Extension NOT IN ('xlsx','xls','avi','jpg','mp4','wmv','png')
        AND (RefContentTypeId IN (11,13,14,35))
    )
```

Comment: try adding onto the end:  as x

Comment: is this MySQL or sql server? the answers can differ

Comment: Why is mysql tag there? Mysql does not support `SELECT INTO`

Comment: @Nick annoyingly SO suggests the MySQL tag when it detects sql, causing lots of tag confusions

Comment: "Mysql does not support SELECT INTO"  MySQL does support it @Nick "MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing." source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland, no, it doesn't! As that page says, it supports `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`

Comment: it is basically the same thing  @Nick

Comment: @RaymondNijland `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and `SELECT...INTO` behave very differently.

Comment: So why does the MySQL documentation say both are the same things? @Larnu Both statements copy data from one table into a other table..

Comment: @Larnu what is the difference between the two? Also thank you, your answer was really helpful!

Comment: one works in SQL-server the other works in MySQL thats the difference  @Yash

Comment: @RaymondNijland it doesn't. it says it is "basically the same". I actually complete disagree with that. For SyBase (SQL Server now) if you were to run `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable SELECT 1 AS i;` The statement will fail, however, `SELECT 1 AS i INTO dbo.MyTable;` will work fine. Conversely `CREATE TABLE MyTable (i int); INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable SELECT 1 AS i;` will work fine, but `CREATE TABLE MyTable (i int); SELECT 1 AS i INTO dbo.MyTable;` will not.

Comment: The `SELECT..INTO` syntax will create the object as part of the statement. if the object already exists, the statement fails. for `INSERT INTO...SELECT` the complete opposite is true; the object must already exist, and if it does not, the statement will fail.

Comment: @Larnu does your answer below create a temp table or an actual table, because when I ran the query twice it says the table is already there. I thought the syntax for temp table was #tablename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you have the nested `SELECT`s. This is what you're more likely after, as you then don't have to alias your subquery:

```
SELECT Url,
       Id
INTO #newtable
FROM Blob
WHERE Id IN (SELECT BlobId FROM XrefBlobProjectMeeting)
  AND Extension NOT IN ('xlsx', 'xls', 'avi', 'jpg', 'mp4', 'wmv', 'png')
  AND (RefContentTypeId IN (11, 13, 14, 35));
```

You'd be ever better off, however, changing the `IN` to an `EXISTS` as well though:

```
SELECT [Url],
       Id
INTO #newtable
FROM Blob B
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM XrefBlobProjectMeeting E
              WHERE E.BlobID = B.ID)
  AND Extension NOT IN ('xlsx', 'xls', 'avi', 'jpg', 'mp4', 'wmv', 'png')
  AND RefContentTypeId IN (11, 13, 14, 35);
```

Comment: Answering your comment on your question, @Yash , as it's in relation to the answer. This would create the temporary table `#newtable`. Any table with a name beginning with `#` is a temporary table, and those with a single `#` will only persist for the duration of the connection that created it.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your problem in your way only and it is working for me. Solution is like given below;

```
SELECT Url,Id
INTO #newtable
    FROM Blob 
    WHERE 
        Id IN 
            (
            SELECT 
                BlobId 
            FROM 
                XrefBlobProjectMeeting
            ) 
        AND Extension NOT IN ('xlsx','xls','avi','jpg','mp4','wmv','png')
        AND (RefContentTypeId IN (11,13,14,35))
```